# How much storage I can get from firebase realtime databse against one email?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm currently working (I basically new in firebase) on an android app that uses Firebase Realtime Database.
As I'm concern that how much storage I have against my email in firebase?

As described in [Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/usage/limits):

1. One path can have maximum 32 level(or child?) deep
2. But It doesn't say how much storage I can get in total!

But I just tried for more than 32 child for a path and I just made 37+ child in a single path and it is still working (a bit slow). Then what does it mean by 32 level? I might get wrong understanding!

So basically I have two question to know:

1. How many child (or level?) can I have in a certain path?
2. How much storage I have against my email? As you know one email can have 15 GB in google drive! So how much in firebase?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Free plan gets 1GB storage in Firebase Realtime Database, you can pay to increase this limit. Details are on the [pricing page](https://firebase.google.com/pricing)

Comment: Thank you very much!

Can you help with the first question?
What does it mean by 32 level?
I made 37+ child in a single path and still working!
@DougStevenson

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 32 levels referred to are levels of nesting of database nodes. Each node would probably be representing an entity, for example:

```
Level 1 node - Country
Level 2 node - City
Level 3 node - Hotel
Level 4 node - Room
Level 5 node - Room Content
```

That is only 5 of the possible 32 levels of nesting.
On each of those levels you can have millions of instances. Each Hotel can for example have hundreds of Rooms.

You should not focus on the 32 levels as it is not recommended to nest too deeply, personally I try never to go below Level 4.

Comment: Thank you dear brother, you just made me clear about this.

Can you suggest me one thing?
Is it good to use firebase as a backend for mobile apps?
Or is there any better backend to use??

Actually I've never used any other backend server !
And firebase seems easy for me!
@GrahamD

Comment: Glad I could help. Many companies, small and large use Firebase. I use the realtime version for my app and am happy. I am sure the other cloud based database/backend providers (Amazon, Microsoft) have similar features in their offerings, if you want to do the research. If you want to stick with Firebase you probably need to decide which NOSQL best suits you. There is also an SQL offering. Check this link as a starting point: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rtdb-vs-firestore